# Extract Image Url in bs4 python beautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I extract **data-layzr** value in python bs4?

Here is the source code

```
<figure ><img src ="#" data-layzr="example.com/wp-content/uploads/img_1.jpg"/></figure>
<figure ><img src ="#" data-layzr="example.com/wp-content/uploads/img_2.jpg"/></figure>
```

I want to extract these two image URL

```
example.com/wp-content/uploads/img_1.jpg
example.com/wp-content/uploads/img_2.jpg
```

I am trying like this but it's not working

```
img_links = soup.find_all('figure')
row_img = [i.find('img')['data-layzr'] for i in img_links]
```

Answer (score 0):

whats the problem here? The code works. If you're reading the html from somewhere use urllib to open it and read before using beautiful soup like this `contents = urllib.request.urlopen('<link to html file>').read()`

```
import bs4
# import urllib.request

contents = '''<figure ><img src ="#" data-layzr="example.com/wp-content/uploads/img_1.jpg"/></figure>
<figure ><img src ="#" data-layzr="example.com/wp-content/uploads/img_2.jpg"/></figure>'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(contents,'html')
img_links = soup.find_all('figure')
row_img = [i.find('img')['data-layzr'] for i in img_links]
print(row_img)
```

This is the output for the above code `['example.com/wp-content/uploads/img_1.jpg', 'example.com/wp-content/uploads/img_2.jpg']`